# How to generate test alert/incident in "Microsoft 365 Defender" portal for test purpose?

Tags: security, azure-security, microsoft365-defender

I want to generate test alert in "Microsoft 365 Defender" portal. I have tried to login
"portal.azure.com" and "outlook.office.com" from tor browser; and I was expecting an alert to be triggered (which isn't of course). any other way possible to test/generate Incident/Alert ?